# NSURL get/set ResourceValue exc_breakpoint

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl

I don't know where to start, I'm really losing my mind so let's jump straight into it.
My app has a file which gets larger while using the app. I do not want it to be backupped in the iCloud and so I use the following part to prevent it:

```
//  load file path
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, TRUE) objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *dbPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"]];

assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[dbPath path]]);

NSError *error;
[dbPath setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
```

This code only works for iOS 5.1 or later, but that is satisfied by the deployment target version. My app is in app store since march this year.

Now the strange thing happens:
I did not work on my app for some months and today I wanted to start the app in simulator. The start went other than expected: I got

```
"Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)"
```

at

```
CoreFoundation`CFHash:
[...]
calll 0x2dafa00   ; symbol stub for: getpid
```

Trace at: http://image-upload.de/file/Tf660h/b341100208.png

StackTrace showed that this occured within [dbPath setResourceValue...].
Although it is stated as a breakpoint I cannot run the app since the marked line.

I did not change anything since my last app store submission and now I am not able to start it. Neither in simulator nor on my devices.
If I try to get the previous flag value with [dbPath getResourceValue...] the same thing happens. I'm trying for hours to understand what happens but no progress.

Comment: Your question title is confusing, as I can't see anything about NSURL in the crash. Also, what has turning off iCloud got to do with the crash you are getting?

Comment: I made an edit to specify that the error occurs at [dbPath setResourceValue...]. That should clarify why NSURL is involved (dbPath is an instance of it). You misread the iCloud part. I dont want to turn it off completely, I just want a specific file to be excluded from being backed up in iCloud and this shall be accomplished with setResourceValue as stated here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html.

Comment: Try posting the full stack trace.

Comment: added link to trace screenshot

Comment: Are you asking ARC, or manual memory management? Judging by the trace you posted, I suspect you have a memory error